# Cloud Storage file convert task in CloudConvert returns "message":"Unauthenticated

Tags: google-cloud-storage, cloudconvert

I have excel xls files in GCS which I am trying to convert to csv using cloudconvert API.
As such I am using the job builder in v2 API to create the necessary curl for extracting file from GCS, transformation and upload.
I have provided the required key, service account, permission to the service account and project details.   Issue is whenever I use the curl formed from CLI I receive the following error -

```
{"message":"Unauthenticated.","code":"UNAUTHENTICATED"}
```

Request sample:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.cloudconvert.com/v2/jobs" \     
-H "Authorization: Bearer API_KEY" \     
-H "Content-type: application/json" \     
-d '{     
      "tasks": {
        "import-1": {             
          "operation": "import/google-cloud-storage",             
          "project_id": "sxxxxxx",             
          "bucket": "testxxxxxx",             
          "client_email": "testxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",             
          "file": "testconvert.xls",             
          "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMII--xxxxx--kQzfSa\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"         
        }     
      } 
    }'
```

Any pointers to what could be wrong is appreciated.  I could not find reference to the error to provide a solution anywhere

Comment: Could you update you post and include how you are calling the request? (don't include your creds!). What are the permissions that you have on the service account you're using?

Comment: For file upload - `curl -X POST "https://api.cloudconvert.com/v2/jobs" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer API_KEY" \
    -H "Content-type: application/json" \
    -d '{
    "tasks": {
        "import-1": {
            "operation": "import/google-cloud-storage",
            "project_id": "sxxxxxx",
            "bucket": "testxxxxxx",
            "client_email": "testxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
            "file": "testconvert.xls",
            "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMII--xxxxx--kQzfSa\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
        }
    }
}' `

Comment: @DonnaldCucharo I gave Storage admin access to the service account used.

Comment: That looks very hard to read. Please include it properly on your post so other members of community can read it easily.

Comment: Have you tried not includinng -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n \n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n on your request?

Comment: Apologies for the editing, I am having trouble using the formatting code, even with the help section.  Also I did try using the private key without begin\end etc.  Same issue in response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to CloudConvert API document:

> To authenticate requests, you need to [create an API key](https://cloudconvert.com/dashboard/api/v2/keys). API keys do not expire unless you revoke them. Requests are authenticated using the Authorization: Bearer **API_KEY** header.

When creating an API key, make sure the following scopes are at least checked:

- task.read
- task.write

From your provided sample requests, it looks like you provided the complete details except the Authorization header.

Your Auth header should then look like this:

```
-H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0exxxxxxxx"
```

Comment: Additional entry formats-"private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvxxxN8CkQzfSa\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"  
Issue was I missed the Authorization portion. Thank you for the help